# Leaving the Visual Studio 6 world for something new ... where to start

Tags: wpf, windows-8

No, you did not misread the title ...

My company has been doing **Visual Studio 6/MFC/DCOM** application for a while now (remember : *these were hot back in 1998*) and I have now the opportunity to start a new application, a new product.

For a lot of reasons (good or bad or both) we want to stay with Microsoft technologies.
Our end customers are big companies that are used to use Windows and desktop applications. For the most of them, they are leaving (or will be leaving in the next year or two) Windows XP for Windows 7 (don't even think of Windows 8).

Qualifying myself of "average developer" I start playing around and came to a working proof of concept build with:

- Visual Studio 2010
- WPF - with the help of Telerik Rad Control for WPF (like it or not, this is not the question)
- MVVM
- Prism

I'm quite happy with it but ... there is a bunch of new buzz words with the upcomming Windows 8.

- WinRT
- Metro applications (there is a preview of Rad controls for Metro)
- XAML or HTML

There is also a lot of bad intentions that are given to Microsoft:

- WFP (and even more Sylverlight) will die
- The desktop application will die to be more web oriented
- etc.

My question would be : What would you do in my situation?

I'm expecting answers of the type:

- I would definitely do *that*
- You could do *that* this way, so it won't block you to update to something else later
- Technology X let you do this while Y this. In your situation I would stick with X for this reason.

Thanks

Comment: This is a polling question and thus not a good fit for SO.

Comment: In your situation I would probably go to Programmers this isn't really covered by SO!

Comment: Voting to move to programmers...

Comment: How can the question be moved to programmers?

Answer (score 3):

I've been developing since the mid-90s, so I know where you're coming from.  I used to work that same technology stack.  Lately, my UI work has revolved around WPF/Silverlight/Prism/MVVM and MVC/HTML/CSS/JQuery.  It looks like your organization's technology skills are geared towards desktop apps, not browser-based.  I think the natural progression will be using XAML-based development, specifically WPF.  Web-based development, I think, will lengthen your new app's development time because it introduces a lot of technologies that may be unfamiliar to your group.

The fear people have these days, as you mention, is that XAML-based apps are on their death-beds.  This may be true, but not anytime time soon and you'll have an option to convert them into WinRT/Metro (C#/XAML stack), if you believe Microsoft.  Some caveats with this approach:

- XAML takes a while to learn
- MVVM and PRISM are difficult concepts for many devs
- Not a lot of devs with these skills when compared to the web-stack

WPF, paired with PRISM in an MVVM pattern, is a powerful desktop development toolkit that can really make you successful with your new project